# Viewport height CSS grid with scrolling sidebar grid cell

Tags: css-grid

I'm trying unsuccessfully to properly set overflow on a sidebar item using CSS grid. My basic layout is this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#dashboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#item-shouldscroll {
  overflow: auto; /* does not work */
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="item-autosized">searchbox</div>
    <div id="item-autosized">other stuff</div>
    <div id="item-shouldscroll">
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">my full height content</div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out what css style to apply to #item-shouldscroll in order for the grid to remain at 100vh. The number of UL list items are unknown as they are fetched via ajax. I'm fairy new to CSS grid, so I hope it's not foolishly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#dashboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#item-shouldscroll {
  overflow: auto; /* does not work */
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I want #dashboard to be 100vh....not 400px.

Comment: Okey.I fixed this problem try again please

Comment: You have to give height to #item-shoulscroll

Comment: I want the height of #item-shouldscroll to be the remaining 1fr of the #sidebar grid rows (as defined). The height needs to follow the remainder of the viewport height. I only want scrolling to begin when the number of items in the ul will make it exceed that space. Setting a height value isn't a solution. I know how to achieve this using flexbox, but was hoping for a CSS grid solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to remove the height from #dashboard, and add it to #sidebar instead:

```
#dashboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  height:100vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```